# Placement of indices in canonical commutation relations of coordinates and conjugate momenta as well as fields and conjugate momenta

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, tensor-calculus, commutator, canonical-conjugation

The canonical commutation relations between generalised coordinates $q_a$ and their conjugate momenta $p^a$ are given by

$[q_a,q_b]=[p^a,p^b]=0$

$[q_a,p^b]=i\delta^b_a$.

Furthermore, the canonical commutation relations between fields $\phi_a(\vec{x})$ and their conjugate momenta $\pi^a(\vec{x})$ are given by

$[\phi_a(\vec{x}),\phi_b(\vec{y})]=[\pi^a(\vec{x}),\pi^b(\vec{y})]=0$

$[\phi_a(\vec{x}),\pi^b(\vec{y})]=i\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})\delta^b_a$.

I would like to ask why **the indices on the generalised coordinates and the fields** are **lower indices** and **the indices on their corresponding conjugate momenta** are **upper indices**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example $q$ a vector field:
$$
q^a=A^\mu
$$
where $a=\mu$ is a *vector index*. The conjugate momentum is
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial A^\mu}
$$
and, as it is an **upper index** in the **denominator**, it makes sense to write it as $\pi_\mu$. Also, you can use the definition of vectors and covectors to prove that $\pi_\mu$ transforms as a covector, and therefore the index must be a lower index.

The same can be said about any kind of tensor field.

**Edit: some more details**

I'll add more details to the discussion above. In particular, I shall "*use the definition of vectors and covectors to prove that $\pi_\mu$ transforms as a covector*"

The components of a vector transform, by definition, as
$$
q'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu q^\nu\tag{1}
$$
while the components of covectors as
$$
\omega'_\mu=\Lambda_\mu{}^\nu \omega_\nu \tag{2}
$$
where
$$
\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu\Lambda_\mu{}^\sigma=\delta^\sigma_\nu \tag{3}
$$

Now, it'll turn out convenient to write $(1)$ in an equivalent form: if we multiply $(1)$ times $\Lambda_\mu{}^\sigma$, and use $(3)$, we get
$$
q^\nu\stackrel{(1,3)}{=}\Lambda_\mu{}^\nu q'^\mu\tag{4}
$$

**Proposition**: the following object
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial q^\mu}\tag{5}
$$
is a *covector*.

**Proof**:

The components of this object, in a new reference frame, are given by
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial q'^\mu}\stackrel{\text{chain-rule}}{=}\frac{\partial q^\nu}{\partial q'^\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^\nu}\stackrel{(4)}{=}\Lambda_\mu{}^\nu \frac{\partial}{\partial q^\nu}\tag{6}
$$
and this is the exact same transformation rule as $(2)$. This proves that $(5)$ is a covector. Therefore, if we have
$$
\pi\sim \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^\mu} \tag{7}
$$
then the object $\pi$ is a covector, and so we write it with a lower idex, $\pi_\mu$.

The discussion above is supposed to convince you that the derivative of something with respect to an object with an upper must have a lower index, and vice-versa:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial A}{\partial h^\color{red}{a}}&=F_\color{red}{a}\\
\frac{\partial B}{\partial j_\color{red}{b}}&=G^\color{red}{b}\tag{8}
\end{align}
for any covariant object $A,B,h,j,F,G$. The discussion above only proved this in the case of $h,j$ vectors, but it is also true for any higher rank kind of tensor (and, barring aside some subtleties, spinors).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! You mention that we "can use the definition of vectors and covectors to prove that $\pi^{\mu}$ trnsforms as a vector." I presume you are referring to the fact that $[q_a,p^b]=i\delta^b_a$, where $q_a$ can be thought of as a covector, $p^b$ can be thought of as a vector, and $i\delta^b_a$ as a number. That's all good and well, but how does this definition of an inner product between vectors and covectors work for $[q_a,q_b]=[p^a,p^b]=0$, where either both are vectors or both are covectors?

Comment: @failexam I edited the post to explain what I meant by "can use the definition of vectors and covectors to prove that $\pi^\mu$ transforms as a vector."